# Axis layout to tabular - vba to vb.net

Tags: excel, vba, vb.net

How to write corresponding line in vb.net

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow
```

I want to set the display of pivot table to Tabular

Comment: See this link : https://www.e-iceblue.com/Knowledgebase/Spire.XLS/Program-Guide/How-to-Create-Pivot-Table-in-Excel-with-C-/VB.NET.html

Comment: What do you have so far? The method is the exact same and in the interop you have the `xlTabularRow` constant. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.pivottable.rowaxislayout?view=excel-pia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the solution was different approach.
Just hiding the subtotals made me accomplish the task